# how to add row in the table dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

How to modify the code to add row in the table dynamically by using javascript?
This is my existing code which is having other functionality. Need one button below the table to add row. I don't need a pop-up which will say how many rows do you want to add. Every single hit will add extra row.

## Javascript

```
var editing = false;

function catchIt(e) {
    if (editing) return;
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.createElement) return;
    if (!e) var obj = window.event.srcElement;
    else var obj = e.target;
    while (obj.nodeType != 1) {
        obj = obj.parentNode;
    }
    if (obj.tagName == 'INPUT' || obj.tagName == 'A') return;
    while (obj.nodeName != 'TD' && obj.nodeName != 'HTML') {
        obj = obj.parentNode;
    }
    if (obj.nodeName == 'HTML') return;
    var x = obj.innerHTML;
    var y = document.createElement('input');
    var z = obj.parentNode;
    z.insertBefore(y, obj);
    z.removeChild(obj);
    y.value = x;
    y.className = 'inp-edit';
    y.onblur = saveEdit;
    y.focus();
    editing = true;
}

function saveEdit() {
    var area = this;
    var y = document.createElement('TD');
    var z = area.parentNode;
    y.innerHTML = area.value;
    z.insertBefore(y, area);
    z.removeChild(area);
    editing = false;
}

document.onclick = catchIt;
```

## HTML

```
    <table border=1 class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr class="portlet-section-header results-header">
            <th class="sorting">Operator ID</th>
            <th class="sorting">Status</th>
            <th class="sorting">First Name</th>
            <th class="sorting">Last Name</th>
            <th class="sorting">Email</th>
            <th class="sorting">Role</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled">Select All
                <br />
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this);" name="check" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Test1</td>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td>wsrc</td>
            <td>wsrc</td>
            <td>aa@aa.com</td>
            <td>SE Admin</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="checkAllRev(this);" name="deleteItem" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>Inactive</td>
            <td>EAI</td>
            <td>SUBSYSTEM</td>
            <td>aa@aa.com</td>
            <td>API</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="checkAllRev(this);" name="deleteItem" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Test3</td>
            <td>Inactive</td>
            <td>Dunning</td>
            <td>Portal</td>
            <td>aa@aa.com</td>
            <td>API</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="5" onclick="checkAllRev(this);" name="deleteItem" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What's `checkAllRev()`, and where should the `button` *be*?

Comment: plz ignore `checkAllRev()`. ADD button can be at the botton of the table (outside table)

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to add to the table? Please take the time to be explicit in your questions, it works out faster for everyone in the end. (My apologies if it feels like I'm hassling you, but so far I have little idea what it is that you want, other than adding rows dynamically; which doesn't explain enough about your request.)

Comment: given code already containing three rows and I want to add as many rows as I want by clicking add another row button (say ADD button only). Currently if you click on any row text you will get that row to be edited. So I have got the functionality for the edit but not for the new add row in the table.

Comment: So you just want to add an empty row of cells?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a template html for your row to be added, and append that html on click of the button.

For example, the row to be added contained two columns and looked some thing like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Active</td>
</tr>
```

You can save this template in a variable. For example:

```
var template = "<tr><td>Test</td><td>Active</td></tr>";
```

Now `append` function of jQuery can be used to add row dynamically.

Since you need to add the row to tbody, following code can be used:

```
$("tbody").append(template);
```

A similar approach can be used to achieve your desired task.

Comment: I had not accepted this answer as it is not giving desired output. Is there any other way around to add row dynamically ?